# JDK 15 download

Tags: java

I'm trying to start programming in Java. I went to JAVA SE Downloads, clicked on the JDK 15 Downloads, selected Windows X64 Installer, agreed to the license, and allowed it to make changes to the computer. When the wizard popped up I followed all of the prompts. A screen came up that said Next Steps or close. I selected next steps which took me to the JDK documentation page. I already had that open so I went back and selected the other option and closed the installer. I selected the Windows, scrolled down to the new folder Java Development Kit, and when I opened it there was a file that led me to the Documentation page, but that was all that was there.

Am I missing a step? How do I get the actual JDK development environment?

Looking forward to starting programming in Java, but can't seem to get the platform started. Thanks for any advice, or questions that may help.

Comment: Pull up `cmd.exe` and type `java -version`. What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the screen in the wizard that says "Next Steps" and "Close", you are pretty much set, the JDK was installed on your computer. To verify that this is the case, you can go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\` (which is typically the default folder). To make sure that Java and the Java Compiler were added to your environment variables, open a command prompt window and type in `java -version` and `javac -version`. You should get a version number for both of those commands. If you do see the `jdk-15` folder in your `C:` drive but don't get the version numbers in the command prompt window, you must add the java bin directory to your environment variables. You can easily find tons of articles showing how to do this on Google by searching for something along the lines of "How to add Java to environment variables".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDK 15 on windows too. After download JDK 15, open the control panel and go to system and security. After that open at system and click at advanced system settings. At advanced system setting, open enviroment variables and select path at system variables and click edit it. After that, go to folder java that you install and open the folder bin in JDK 15. Copy the destination folder JDK 15 bin like this ''C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin'' and add new at path enviroment variable. After that, click new in system variable. At variable name I put JAVA_HOME and variable value, you copy the JDK 15 file path and paste like this ''C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15'' (Note that you folder is not the same as mine). After that, open cmd (command promt) and type java -version to know your version. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Not a good question to be asked here. Read the documentation and try out yourself. While you wait for your setup to complete, don't waste time and go to an online editor and start learning. Happy Java!